# Context used for Toasts

Tags: android

In a lot of examples, I notice that that they are created like this:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Toast Text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Generally, it has been my habit to just use the 'this' keyword for the Activity I am in and it works perfectly fine.

Is there any compelling argument for using application context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The previous answer is simply not correct.   Check out CommonsWare's answer to this question at this similar post:

[When to call activity context OR application context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context)

You most often WANT to use 'this' (which is the Activities context).

Comment: NP - yeah, my answer is so weak next to his.  Oh, well.